# Associating original data with Kmeans clusters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am using scikit-learn. Suppose we have data as follows:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
b = [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 4, 2]
c = [2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4]
```

and we run the following:

```
temp.append(a)
temp.append(b)
temp.append(c)
k_data.append(temp)

k_means = cluster.KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=2, n_init=5)
k_means.fit(np.array(k_data))
```

I understand that K-means will assign its own clusters and labels to each entry, each label corresponding to a cluster. The cluster centers here will be 9 dimensional vectors. Is there a way to know how much each data entry is effective towards forming that cluster/cluster center? eg for cluster_1/cluster_center_1 it used 33% of a's entries, 10% of b's and 57% of c's entries.

Looking at the K-means methods and attributes, there is no direct way. Especially that K-means accepts arrays as inputs.

Comment: It seems like you want the 1 from array a to be traceable separately from the 1 in array b; it isn't, but they will be in the same group, since they have the same value. Instead, you can match the values post-analysis, which will give you what you need. Does that make sense?

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: Basically, since you have the clusters that contain each point, you can find which sets each points come from. Then rerun the analysis using leave-one-out, and find what the new clusters are, and see how much each matters.

Comment: You may be thinking about the issue wrong - k-means clustering is an iterative process that always either includes or excludes a point from a given cluster. It doesn't have a weight of influence, per se.

Comment: I finally did it using the input output order symmetry, which worked fine, I then assessed each cluster center to assign an overall label if applicable eg a, b or c overall.

Comment: @plumSemPy mind sharing the code?

Comment: hey @payne this was a long time ago and I do not have the code. Though looking at my question, I think it is a wrong question to be asking, I agree with David. All the dimensions in a 9-dimensional vector are used to calculate the cluster center of a cluster. There is no weighting.

Comment: @plumSemPy maybe have a look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764453/associating-region-index-with-true-labels). I might have misunderstood your question thinking it was the same as mine?